# Why can't we pickle an instance of InteractiveInterpreter?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

An attempt to pickle an instance of InteractiveInterpreter results in the following error

```
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 725, in save_inst
    save(stuff)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle ellipsis objects
```

which is strange InteractiveInterpreter isn't an Ellipsis object according to what I know. Any reasons? And is there any alternate way to pickle InteractiveInterpreter Object?

Comment: Presumably a child object of the `InteractiveInterpreter` instance is. When you pickle something things are pickled recursively.

Comment: You can try to handle them with `__set/getstate__`

Comment: By the way, strange that `Ellipsis` is not picklable... it's just a singleton like `None`, I don't see any problem in pickling it.

Answer (score 1):

By some reason `Ellipsis` cannot be pickled in the stock pickler. But you can use [`persistent id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-external-objects) functionality to achieve this.

First, instead of `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load` you should use `Pickler` and `Unpickler` objects.

Second, you must define two functions - first will take an object and return its id (or `None` for regular pickling) and second will convert this id to object on unpickling.

Working example:

```
import cPickle as pickle

def dump_ellipsis(obj):
    if obj is Ellipsis:
        return "Ellipsis"

def load_ellipsis(persid):
    if persid == "Ellipsis":
        return Ellipsis


storage = open("tmp.pkl", "w")

pickler = pickle.Pickler(storage)

pickler.persistent_id = dump_ellipsis

pickler.dump(Ellipsis)

storage.close()

storage = open("tmp.pkl")

unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(storage)

unpickler.persistent_load = load_ellipsis

print unpickler.load()
```